# Why does my line fit result in a gradient of np.nan when line fitting in Log-Log scale?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, curve-fitting

I'm trying to find the gradient under which my graph is plotted whilst line fitting in the double log scale. Therefore I've written the function below.

```python
def calc_coefficients_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    wnss = white_noise_signal_shift(n, N, num, shift, operations)

    whitenoise_filtered = np.abs(wnss[1][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    shifted_whitenoise = np.abs(wnss[4][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    x = np.linspace(1, n, n // 2)

    original_coefficients = []
    shifted_coefficients = []

    for i in range(num):
        original_coefficients.append(np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(whitenoise_filtered[:, i]), 1))
        shifted_coefficients.append(np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(shifted_whitenoise[:, i]), 1))

    original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients = \
        np.asarray((original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients))

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 7.5))

    ax1.plot(whitenoise_filtered)
    ax1.loglog(10 ** (original_coefficients.mean() * np.log10(x) + 1), 'r')
    ax1.set_title('Original noise')

    ax2.loglog(shifted_whitenoise)
    ax2.loglog(10 ** (shifted_coefficients.mean() * np.log10(x) + 1), 'r')
    ax2.set_title('Shifted noise')

    print(original_coefficients.mean(), shifted_coefficients.mean())
```

---

The goal of the function `calc_coefficients_signal_shift` is to find whether the gradient of the graph changes after shifting the signal. I expect it to be somewhere around `-5/3.` since that is the value I applied after my imports in the function `white_noise` with the variable `slope_loglog` (filtering the noise under said slope coefficient). When a `0` is entered for the number of `operations` the shift is performed it should result in identical arrays for both coefficients. However, it results in `nan` for the original noise and a real value for the shifted noise (which is in this case not shifted at all, thus the original noise).

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

> NOTE: you may assume that the shift operation is working properly since I've been debugging that one for a while now and it behaves as it should. This question is purely about my line fitting function.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import numpy.random as rnd

# slope to use for every function
grad = -5 / 3.

rnd.seed(10)

def white_noise(n: int, N: int, slope: int = grad):
    x = np.linspace(1, n, n // 2)
    slope_loglog = 10 ** (slope * np.log10(x) + 1)

    whitenoise = rnd.randn(n // 2, N) + 1j * rnd.randn(n // 2, N)
    whitenoise[0, :] = 0  # zero-mean noise
    whitenoise_filtered = whitenoise * slope_loglog[:, np.newaxis]

    whitenoise = np.concatenate((whitenoise, whitenoise[0:1, :], np.conj(whitenoise[-1:0:-1, :])), axis=0)
    whitenoise_filtered = np.concatenate(
        (whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_filtered[0:1, :], np.conj(whitenoise_filtered[-1:0:-1, :])), axis=0)

    whitenoise_signal = fft.ifft(whitenoise_filtered, axis=0)
    whitenoise_signal = np.real_if_close(whitenoise_signal)
    if np.iscomplex(whitenoise_signal).any():
        print('Warning! whitenoise_signal is complex-valued!')
    whitenoise_retransformed = fft.fft(whitenoise_signal, axis=0)

    return whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal, whitenoise_retransformed, slope_loglog

def random_arrays(N: int, num: int):
    res = np.asarray(range(N))
    rnd.shuffle(res)

    return res[:num]


def modified_roll(inp, shift: int, operations: int):
    count = 0
    array = inp[:]
    array_rolled = array.copy()

    for k in range(operations):
        count += shift
        array = np.roll(array, shift, axis=0)
        array[:count] = 0
        array_rolled += array

    out = array_rolled / operations

    return out


def white_noise_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal = white_noise(n, N)[:3]

    # only showing the selected arrays
    arrays_to_select = random_arrays(N, num)
    selected_whitenoise = whitenoise[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_filtered = whitenoise_filtered[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_signal = whitenoise_signal[:, arrays_to_select].copy()

    # shifting the signal as a field of different refractive index would do
    if operations == 0:
        shifted_signal = selected_whitenoise_signal
    else:
        shifted_signal = modified_roll(selected_whitenoise_signal.copy(), shift, operations)

    # fourier transform back to the power frequency domain
    shifted_whitenoise = fft.fft(shifted_signal, axis=0)

    return selected_whitenoise, selected_whitenoise_filtered, selected_whitenoise_signal, shifted_signal, \
           shifted_whitenoise

def calc_coefficients_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    wnss = white_noise_signal_shift(n, N, num, shift, operations)

    whitenoise_filtered = np.abs(wnss[1][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    shifted_whitenoise = np.abs(wnss[4][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    x = np.linspace(1, n, n // 2)

    original_coefficients = []
    shifted_coefficients = []

    for i in range(num):
        original_coefficients.append(np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(whitenoise_filtered[:, i]), 1))
        shifted_coefficients.append(np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(shifted_whitenoise[:, i]), 1))

    original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients = \
        np.asarray((original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients))

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 7.5))

    ax1.loglog(whitenoise_filtered)
    ax1.loglog(10 ** (original_coefficients.mean() * np.log10(x) + 1), 'r')
    ax1.set_title('Original noise')

    ax2.loglog(shifted_whitenoise)
    ax2.loglog(10 ** (shifted_coefficients.mean() * np.log10(x) + 1), 'r')
    ax2.set_title('Shifted noise')

    print(original_coefficients.mean(), shifted_coefficients.mean())

calc_coefficients_signal_shift(200, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I observe that you are wise in the ways of the random seed.

Comment: It should work without a random seed, it doesn't matter which is used or whether it is used at all. If ```calc_coefficients_signal_shift(200, 100, 100, 0, 0)``` is filled out like this it should return something in the proximity of -5/3. With or without a random seed.

Comment: True, yet your code's results are more repeatable with the seed - both in values and performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that `slope_loglog` was defined incorrectly. The way it was defined was correct for plotting a straight line in the double-log graph, but since I was studying power-law behavior I needed to use the power-law formula. So, `slope_loglog` became `c * x ** m`, with `c = 10` (or whatever value I want to use, since that doesn't affect the outcome that much) and `m` being the gradient I want to calculate.

Implementing this with the function `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` handed me the end result.

```python
def calc_coefficients_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    wnss = white_noise_signal_shift(n, N, num, shift, operations)

    whitenoise_filtered = np.abs(wnss[1][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    shifted_whitenoise = np.abs(wnss[4][0:n // 2, :]).copy()
    x = np.linspace(1, n, n // 2)

    original_coefficients = []
    shifted_coefficients = []

    for i in range(num):
        original_coefficients.append(curve_fit(lambda x, m: c * x ** m, x, whitenoise_filtered[:, i], p0=(-5/3.))[0][0])
        shifted_coefficients.append(curve_fit(lambda x, m: c * x ** m, x, shifted_whitenoise[:, i])[0][0])

    original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients = \
        np.asarray((original_coefficients, shifted_coefficients))

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 7.5))

    ax1.loglog(whitenoise_filtered)
    ax1.loglog(c * x ** original_coefficients.mean(), 'k:', label=f'Slope: {np.round(original_coefficients.mean(), 3)}')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Log(f)')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Log(p)')
    ax1.set_title('Original noise')
    ax1.legend(loc=0)

    ax2.loglog(shifted_whitenoise)
    ax2.loglog(c * x ** shifted_coefficients.mean(), 'k:', label=f'Slope: {np.round(shifted_coefficients.mean(), 3)}')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Log(p)')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Log(f)')
    ax2.set_title('Shifted noise')
    ax2.legend(loc=0)
    plt.tight_layout()

    print(f'The mean of the original coefficients is: {stats.describe(original_coefficients)}')
    print(f'The mean of the shifted coefficients is: {stats.describe(shifted_coefficients)}')
```